# BTS ESB Storing EndPoints information

Tags: storage, biztalk, endpoints, biztalk2006r2, esb-toolkit-2.0

Which method would be the best to store EndPoints information in programmable repository rather than hard-coding in BizTalk ESB2.0 tool kit?

Answer (score 0):

For this we can use UDDI Portal and to Access the UDDI portal we can to configure UDDI resolver!